# Systemctl Services start with Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, systemctl

I have a start script that checks if the service is active/inactive and starts it if necessary:

```
!/usr/bin/sh

# Set up the trap to catch errors
trap 'catch $? $LINENO' ERR

function catch() {
  echo "An error occurred on line $2 with exit status $1"
  exit 1
}

# Set the script to exit immediately on errors
#set -e

# define the services list
SERVICES=(service1 service2 service3)
for service in $SERVICES
do
echo "Checking $service status"
STATUS="$(systemctl is-active $service)"
echo "status is ${STATUS}"
RUNNING="$(systemctl show -p SubState $service | cut -d'=' -f2)"
echo "Running status is $RUNNING"
if [ "${STATUS}" = "active" ]; then
        echo "$service Service is Active"
        if [ "${RUNNING}" = "running" ]; then
                echo "$service Service is Running"
        else
                echo "$service Service Not Running"
        fi
else
        echo "Returned ${STATUS} for $service. Starting it... "
        systemctl start $service
        echo "$service started"
fi
done
```

When running 'sh start.sh' I get 'An error occurred on line 19 with exit status 3'
What is the cause for it ? I do not see any syntax errors.

Comment: Btw.: Fix your shebang and then paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: you can debug your script by using "sh -x" as shebang (currently it is broken). 'SERVICES=(service1 service2 service3)' does not work as expected !!! check the content of $SERVICES

Comment: So you want to start the service if its not running, if so then what about only starting the service everytime via systemctl, as systemctl already desinged to start the stopped services and do nothing if service is already running. Why a complex script required to start the stopped services.

Comment: What unix distro are u using?

Answer (score 1):

Systemctl man page: is-active can return an exit code non-zero if no active

```
is-active PATTERN...
           Check whether any of the specified units are active (i.e.
           running). Returns an exit code 0 if at least one is active,
           or non-zero otherwise. Unless --quiet is specified, this will
           also print the current unit state to standard output.
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Exit%20status

Comment: This sort of thing -- not having a way to distinguish "there was an error" from "the test came back negative" -- is one of several reasons that `set -e` is not a really good idea. See [BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`, or `trap ERR`) do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for an allegory and more examples.